DocuSign account-d website not working with MS Word Documents

Content Controls should ONLY show in MS Word application, it should never show the tags in DocuSign. This is on account-d.docusign site. They seem to have broken it and we need it fixed. Tried to reach out to DocuSign but they haven't replied.
Our code has been the same for over a year, nothing has changed, we just send the envelope with the .docx file. All our .docx files have always had content controls in them, and would never appear in DocuSign, until a couple week ago, as they are like merge tokens and the only thing that matters is the text between the open and close token, But now those tokens/content controls are showing up in DocuSign.

Please edit your question and provide an API log (omit sensitive data) so we can see an example of what is happening. Also, contact DocuSign developer support.

How do I contact developer support? It says in support that I have to pay. sendEnvelope is what we call in the Java sdk with the .docx file as the doc parameter. But that’s actually irrelevant since it’s the same for over a year. It is there DocuSign site that is broken displaying word documents, it has always hidden the content control surrounding tags and now out stopped and is showing them. I do need them to fix their door but haven’t found a way that they actually see my request.
